# understanding discrete-time convolution

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I'm trying to understand the discrete-time convolution for LTIs and its graphical representation. standard explanations (like: [this one](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-4-convolution/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf)) start with the idea of decomposing an input signal $x[t]$ into a sum of unit impulses. We have unit impulse function $\delta$:

$\delta[n] = 1\ if\ n = 0, 0\ if n \neq 0$

then $x[t]$ can be represented as:

$x[t] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}x[k]\delta[t-k]$

so the input signal at $t$, $x[t]$, can be represented this way because $\delta[t-k]$ is going to be 1 only if $t = k$, and 0 elsewhere. this makes great sense.

the confusion for me begins in **Transparency 4.2** of above [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-4-convolution/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf). the left hand side makes perfect sense, but what does the right represent? how does one unit impulse generate a sequence of responses? what does $x[0]h[n]$ represent here? How do you go from this to **Transparency 4.9** where $h$ is used instead of $\delta$?

put differently: can someone explain the intuition behind $h$ (the response of a an LTI system) being reflected and time shifted? in the above trick for representing simply the input signal $x[t]$, there's no time shifting really; $\delta[t-k]$ seems like just a mathematical trick for getting a $1$ in the right place and zero elsewhere; it's not intuitive for me to think of it as time shifted.

Comment: Please ask the moderators to move this dsp.SE where you will find lots of answers (for example, [this one](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6355/235)) spelling out some parts of what you want to know in great detail. You can contact the moderators by clicking on the "flag" link below your question